# create am Empty GDB using ogr2ogr

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I guess no one has not asked this question yet.

Let's say if I want to store my CSV to GDB feature table then the code below works just fine

`ogr2ogr -f "filegdb" test.gdb my.csv`

and I thought just creating an empty GDB is

`ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" test.gdb`

and obviously it does not work.

Will there be a way to create an empty GDB using ogr2ogr?

Comment: I guess it is not possible, but it should be possible to import some data into table "foo" and drop it with ogrinfo `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "DROP TABLE foo" test.gdb`.

Comment: @user30184 you are right. I guess it is not possible to create an empty GDB somehow. In order to use sqlite dialect, I have to add the driver, which is not a big deal. Yet, I think I could make a dummy CSV and import it to GDB that I want to create and drop the CSV after. In this case, I do not have to install extra driver that I rarely use.

Comment: I believe that some parts of SQLite are compiled into GDAL by default and "drop table" is basic SQLite function https://sqlite.org/lang.html.